# Update preferences when working with application template

Tags: saving, settings, template

I have setup 3.6 LTS with application templates. One for production, one with minimal addons and a factory default one.

As described in the Blender docs, those template files are stored in the script folder, inside a folder called "bl_app_templates_user", inside the AppData/Blender Foundation/scripts/startup/ folder.

All well understood and setup. But... When I want to update the preferences using Edit -> Preferences -> Save Preferences, a folder is created inside the config folder.

While I can reload the application template specific preferences, there's no way to directly save the preferences for the current application template.

[image: Save Preferences Dialog]

Instead, I have to copy the userpref.blend file manually into the correct place. Or Blender will not startup using my latest adjustments to the preferences.

I am wondering if someone encountered this and found an elegant solution? Or I should probably post that as an enhancement request...

Thanks!